# cmake source_group has no effect

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I'm trying to organize a project generated for visual studio 2015 using the `source_group` function to add specific folders to the project, but it have no effect, here is how i do it:

```
set(CPP_FILES_REGEX "\\b(\\w|\\d)+\\b\\.(hpp|cpp|c|h)")

source_group("my_folder" REGULAR_EXPRESSION     "${sourcers_dir}\/${CPP_FILES_REGEX}")

add_executable(my_executable ${sourcers_dir}/main.cpp ${sourcers_dir}/test.hpp)
```

Testes the regex here: [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) and it works fine so the executables are being match. I also tried to add the file name but it still have no effect:

```
set(CPP_FILES_REGEX "\\b(\\w|\\d)+\\b\\.(hpp|cpp|c|h)")

source_group("my_folder" FILES "${sourcers_dir}/main.cpp")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMake's regexes are fairly basic in what they understand, see the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#regex-specification). "Fancy" named classes and pseudo-classes like `\b`, `\w` or `\d` are not supported. You'll have to spell them out manually (i.e. use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` etc.)